# Making a survey in node.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, survey

I need help with creating a survey app. My idea is for the app to display questions and have users click buttons to answer. At the end, the app should show each user which user had answers closest to theirs. I need help with the following things:

*How to set up the questions and buttons for the answers

*How to compare all the answers and show each user at the end

*How to make it so there is a separate url for each survey being taken

Answering any of these questions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For grouping the participants by how close their answers are, you could use the [k-means clustering algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), of which there's already a [JavaScript implementation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kmeans-js) you could use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see where Socket.io fits, other than that you could use [Survey.js Library](https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library/)  to help you build the interface, store the data in the same format, JSON, in [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/). There you can group like [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), returning the documents data of same value.